# How to add new property to node template that will be saved to Json diagram model using GoJS?

Tags: json, gojs

I mean on type of application with palette on the left and diagram area on the right side.

For example I have the following node template:

```
var inputTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Spot",
    nodeStyle(),
    $(go.Shape, "Circle", shapeStyle1(),
        { fill: red }),  // override the default fill (from shapeStyle1()) to be red
    $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(false),  // the only port
        { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(1, 0.5) }),
    {
        doubleClick: function (e, obj) {
            window.open("http://www.microsoft.com", "_blank");
    }}
    );
```

And want to add Guid property on node level that will appear in Json model when we save the diagram using toJson function. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many properties as you like to the model data. Just be sure that the property name does not start with an underscore ("_") and that the property value is JSON-serializable. Read about the requirements at https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html.

If you want to use GUIDs as key values, first make sure that all of your existing node data have unique GUID string values. And set Model.makeUniqueKeyFunction to a function that returns a new GUID string.

This is a duplicate of https://forum.nwoods.com/t/how-to-add-new-property-to-node-template-that-will-be-saved-to-json-diagram-model/8726.